# How can you identify an iPad without a home button?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad

I need to adjust the area where my game plays whenever it runs on a device without a home button.

I can identify all of the iDevices by their dimensions, but the new iPad 12.9" has the same dimensions as the old one.

This code works but I’m looking for something more future proof that doesn’t rely on the name. Any thoughts?

```
if ( [ [[UIDevice currentDevice] name] isEqualToString: @"iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation)" ] ) {
    device = LFDeviceTypePadPro12_9;
}
```

Comment: Safe area guides?

Comment: @JordanS I’m using safeAreaInsets but I need to bump up some of them for reasons I don’t remember.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [LAContext](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext) [.biometryType](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/localauthentication/lacontext/2867583-biometrytype) to get the Biometric login type supported by the device.  On old devices it's going to be `.none` or `.touchId`, while newer devices have `.faceID`.  The faceId devices have no home button; everything else does.

Comment: Interesting suggestion Josh. Unfortunately it only works if authentication is enabled. So it works on my phone where I have touchID enabled, but it doesn’t work on my iPad where I never set up authentication even though there is a touchID button.